# umbraco richtext editor skip UI css

Tags: html, css, umbraco, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use richtext editor from umbraco... and in html area I put something like

```
<ui id="col">
  <li>mycontent</li>
</ui>
```

Now when I try to save it... it skips my css and converts my code to

```
<ui>
  <li>mycontent</li>
</ui>
```

Why is umbraco not saving my css id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the culprit is the tinymce editor. Check out this link for workarounds that may help: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-(tinymce)/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor

Comment: :)... I was actually just going over that article... that maybe it E.J... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: btw... do you know if that happens in Umbraco 5?

Comment: Not sure about v5, but you do know v5 has been cancelled, right? It's not something you want to pick for a new project.

Comment: dang??? really??? thanks E.J... it was back of my mind... phew!!! u r a lifesaver